# Why zero absent when convert float numbers (which are between 0 and 1) to string

Tags: java, oracle, floating-point

In Oracle database, I store a number 0.5 in a column with format number(17, 2).
And I read it using a Java program (with mybatis), and store as a string field of an entity object. The value of this string field is ".5", and not "0.5" as I expect.

I know ".5" is a standard represent of float numbers, and can be directly convert to number 0.5 in most programming language. But It's just not I want when it is displayed on web pages. Of course I can always convert to "0.5" whenever I want by just checking if the first letter is ".", I think it's trivial and easy to forget.

I can also use a Oracle function to specify a format for converting numbers to strings. But the TO_CHAR() function take a format pattern as parameter to make the output string to be fix length, or take no format parameter to print 0.5 as ".5". Both behaviors are not I want. I just want a "as it" way to convert numbers. But oracle's "as it" way is not what I want.

So I want to ask:

What's the better way to handle this issue?

Comment: You read it with what Java program? and store it as a String field of an entity object how? and why? It should be a `double` or more probably a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @EJP Yes, finally we had made it stored as a BigDecimal. And, how can I choose a comment as the best answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should not confuse the value of a number with its representation.

`0.5`, `.5`, `1/2, 2-1, 334/668, 0.12 and 0000000.50000000000` are *all* the exact same value.

If you want that value formatted in a certain way, you will need to specify that when you turn the value into a string.

Comment: What I ask is exactly how to specify the format when turn the value into a string from source (for this situation, the Oracle database or mybatis, because it is Oracle or mybatis who dose the turning stuff)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `mybatis` however, 
couldn't you just read it as `double` and then format it e.g. with decimal formater ?

`DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
df.format(number);`